# How to add missing options (control panel in start menu & date format) in Windows 10 Creators update?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, date-time

I recently updated to the Windows 10 creators update and noticed that the option to access the control panel was removed from the start menu and an option for the date time format as well.

Is there any way to get them back? See the below screenshots for more detail.

[image: Time format settings]
[image: Control panel missing from start menu]

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQa1L.png)

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We are always glad to help, but this probably should have been two separate questions.

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Likely easier than editing the registry [Win X Menu Editor](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.30) will let you put the control panel shortcut back.

For the date formats you should use the Control Panel advanced functions to set up custom schemes:

- Open Control Panel.
- Click on the Clock, Language, and Region link.
- Click on the Change date, time, or numbers formats link.
- Under the Formats tab, click on the ***Additional settings*** button.