# How to add missing options in Start Menu of Windows 10 Creators update?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Earlier Windows 10 version in my desktop computer was 1607.

And I recently updated to the Windows 10 creators version 1703.

In Windows 10 Creator version 1703, **App and Features** is added but **Control Panel** is removed.

[image]

Without using any third party application,

May I add edit/add options in Start Menu of Windows 10 Creator version 1703 so that **Control Panel** can be added in Start Menu?

If yes, please let me know how to do it?

Regards

FewL

Comment: This question looks familar.  Did you delete the previous instance of this question?  You should always improve a question, instead of deleting it, and publishing it again.  Continue removal of questions to republish them will lead to question bans.

Comment: I see what happen....[You decided to change an existing question to something else entirely.](https://superuser.com/questions/1206304/how-to-add-missing-date-format-in-windows-10-creators-update)

Comment: My previous question, "How to add missing options (control panel in start menu & date format) in Windows 10 Creators update?" is put on hold. And the suggestion is "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.". Therefore, I edited my previous question separated two distinct questions in two questions. However, my previous question is on hold and this question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: If you have a different question, ask the question, don't edit a previous question and morph it into an entirely different question.  Otherwise people are going to notice and bring the behavior to the attention of a moderator.

Comment: Use [Win-X Editor](http://winaero.com/blog/winx-menu-editor-v3-0/) to customize the menu

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can add it to the start menu is by pinning it or take a shortcut and dragging/dropping into the start menu. You can't add it back like it used to be. Easiest thing would be to type Control Panel into Search, then right-click Pin to Start.

Microsoft is doing this to force you to use the "Settings" app.

Or you can replace that start menu with ClassShell
http://www.classicshell.net/

Comment: "The only way you can add it to the start menu is by pinning it or take a shortcut and dragging/dropping into the start menu." - **How** is this done exactly?

Comment: I will be clear: *I know how* to do pin something to the start menu.  The author might not know how to do so.